# Comparing floats as string! can I? Is it valid approach?

Tags: c#, floating-point

In order to check if difference between two float numbers is 0.01 I do this

```
if ((float1 - float.Parse(someFloatAsStringFromXML).ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString() == "0,01000977")
```

Is this type of "approach" is acceptable? Is there better way? How to?

p.s. I'm very new to c# and strong typing languages! So, if you have more than brief explanation, I would love to read it!

I forgot to mention, that numbers are "353.58" and "353.59". I have them as strings with dot "." not "," that is the reason why I use float.Parse

Comment: That's got to be the wrong way to do it. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: This is not even valid syntax. And why don't you compare floats as floats?

Comment: Use `Decimal`, not strings or floats, if you want precise comparison

Comment: "," vs "." shouldn't be the reason you pick `float`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what kind of data is stored in `float1` or `someFloatAsStringFromXML`? Money or mathematical values usually require the `decimal` type, while `double` and `float` are more suited for things like weight or length... Given that you cannot ever measure the absolute exact length or weight of something, then checking if a difference between two values is 0.01 is wrong on a more fundamental level (or requires rounding to begin with). If you're comparing financial data then you should be using decimals instead.

Comment: `decimal` isn't a cure-all either, it's still a floating point number, but a decimal one. It happens to work in this case, but it's not something you can just throw around everywhere and expect equality comparisons to make sense.

Comment: @Shaamaan Both variables stores data, that represents money

Comment: @harold Nobody said that. But in the case of currency, it is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: @ezi If both variables store financial data, then it's a mistake to store them as `float` to begin with. If possible, I'd encourage you to change the type, both in your application and in the XML (if possible), and then you will have no problems at all making the comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give an example of your two numbers

```
353.58
353.59
```

These numbers cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point format. Also, the value `0.01` cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point format. Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

So, for example, when you try to represent `353.58` as a `float`, there is no `float` with that value and you get the closest float value which happens to be [353.579986572265625](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=353.58).

In my view you are using the wrong data type to represent these values. You need to be using a decimal format. That will allow you to represent these values exactly. In C# you use the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) type.

Then you can write:

```
decimal value1 = 353.58m;
decimal value2 = 353.59m;
Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(value2-value1) == 0.01m);
```

Use [`decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks098hd7.aspx) or [`decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) to convert from your textual representation of the number into a `decimal` value.

Comment: But unfortunately you've selected the wrong solution. Using a comparison against epsilon is the wrong way to handle this.

Comment: Yes, I know! That is because I did not read this at that time. I implemented this solution instead.

Comment: @ezi Look at the end of my answer: I said that you should be using `decimal`! I even put it in **bold text**! Indeed, my last comment to you there was that you should probably be using `decimal`. :)

Comment: Can you explain why Math.Abs is necessary in particular case?

Comment: @ezi It's there so it makes no difference whether value1 is 0.1 bigger than value2, or value2 is 0.1 bigger than value1. If you ONLY want value2 to be 0.1 bigger than value1 then you should use `if ((value2-value1) == 0.1)`

Comment: @MatthewWatson For the record I was not asking ezi to change the accepted answer. My comment was a response to ezi's now deleted comment where she states that she used epsilon and that it works well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's no problem at all; I was just telling him off for not reading my answer to the end! :)  (I've maxed my rep for today so it makes no difference to me anyway ;)

Comment: I deleted that comment because I do not use epsilon case any more. I accepted David's answer because some details clarifies better. I did't knew that I will get closest float value which happens to be 353.579986572265625. Basically you both are correct. btw, I'm not "she" I'm "he", but what ever, lol! ^^

Comment: @ezi It's all fine: As long as you have the solution, job's a good-un!

Comment: @ezi Unfortunately English doesn't have any gender neutral version of he or she, so I just picked she so as not to offend women by assuming that all programmers are men!!  ;-)

Comment: ;D mkay, thnx 4 help @all! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Firtly, you should always compare numbers as their underlying types (float, double, decimal), NOT as strings.

Now, you might think that you can compare like so:

```
float floatFromXml = float.Parse(someFloatAsStringFromXML);

if (Math.Abs(float1 - floatFromXml) == 0.01)
```

My example works as follows:

Firstly, calculate the difference between the two values:

```
float1 - floatFromXml
```

Then take the absolute value of that (which just removes the minus sign)

```
Math.Abs(float1 - floatFromXml)
```

Then see if that value is equal to 0.01:

```
if (Math.Abs(float1 - floatFromXml) == 0.01)
```

And if you *don't* want to ignore the sign, you wouldn't do the `Math.Abs()` part:

```
if ((float1 - floatFromXml) == 0.01)
```

**But that won't work for your example because of rounding errors!**

Because you are using floats (and this would apply to doubles too) you are going to get rounding errors which makes comparing the difference to 0.01 impossible. It will be more like 0.01000001 or some other slightly wrong value.

To fix that, you have to compare the actual difference to the target difference, and if that is only different by a tiny amount you say "that'll do".

In the following code, `target` is the target difference that you are looking for. In your case, it is `0.01`.

Then `epsilon` is the smallest amount by which `target` can be wrong. In this example, it is `0.00001`.

What we are saying is "if the difference between the two numbers is within 0.00001 of 0.1, then we will consider it as matching a difference of 0.1".

So the code calculates the actual difference between the two numbers, `difference`, then it sees how far away that difference is from `0.01` and if it is within `0.00001` it prints "YAY".

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void Run()
        {
            float f1 = 353.58f;
            float f2 = 353.59f;

            if (Math.Abs(f1 - f2) == 0.01f)
                Console.WriteLine("[A] YAY");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("[A] Oh dear"); // This gets printed.

            float target = 0.01f;
            float difference = Math.Abs(f2 - f1);
            float epsilon = 0.00001f; // Any difference smaller than this is ok.

            float differenceFromTarget = Math.Abs(difference - target);

            if (differenceFromTarget < epsilon)
                Console.WriteLine("[B] YAY"); // This gets printed.
            else
                Console.WriteLine("[B] Oh dear"); 
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**However, the following is probably the answer for you**

Alternatively, you can use [the `decimal` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of floats, then the direct comparison will work (for this particular case):

```
decimal d1 = 353.58m;
decimal d2 = 353.59m;

if (Math.Abs(d1 - d2) == 0.01m)
    Console.WriteLine("YAY"); // This gets printed.
else
    Console.WriteLine("Oh dear");
```

Comment: The code in the question attempts to check if the difference is exactly 0.01. So your >= is wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm guessing that he really wants to check if it's greater than, or greater than or equals - but I'll update my answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson What I want is exact difference - .01, so David is correct. I need == not >=

Comment: I edited my question. At first, both are as string. Then they are converted with float.Parse

Comment: @ezi Ok, I've updated my answer. You won't be able to get an exact difference with floats. I think you should probably use `decimal` (which has got a `Parse()` method you can use, like `float` does).

Answer (score 0):

In direct answer to your question, can you do this? Yes. Is it a valid approach? Almost certainly not.

If you give some more context, you will get more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good way of doing it. There's no need to compare it to a string and you don't gain anything by doing it that way. Compare it to an actual float value.

The immediately visible problem with your approach there is it's not culture safe. In the UK we use `.` instead of `,` as the decimal point - so the result of `.ToString()` wouldn't match at all. But aside from that it's just bad practice to do that without a good reason.

Comment: "so the result of .ToString() wouldn't match at all" can you explain?

Comment: If I did `.ToString()` on a float - it'd have a "." in instead of a "," - e.g. "124.56" instead of "124,56" - and since you're comparing strings - "124.56" is not equal to "124,56" even though its the same number.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, that I understand what you mean.. . So "123.45" toString will differ from "123,45" toString?

Comment: @chba [Wikipedia has a good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) about how different countries and cultures represent numbers and currency in print. So you see the decimal mark can be a dot or a comma.  If you parse text strings designed for printing in a specific culture, you have to use the correct method and parameters, e.g. in C# `Decimal.TryParse(..)` has a parameter for specifying the allowable string patterns.